# How to prevent jumping to top of the page when clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been stuck on how to prevent jumping to the top of the page when clicking on a link that has parsing PHP data.

I have tried so many things, like preventDefault or return false or putting "/" at the end, but unfortunately with no success.
Observation: this is linking to the same page, but is sending a php value.

The link looks like this:

```
<a id="chatLink" href="explore.php?user_id=<?php echo $row['unique_id']?>"
```

Comment: Please show us your **rendered** HTML.

Comment: Are you describing the browser jumping to the top of the new page when it loads, or before the previous page unloads?

Comment: which one is that? I am new to this

Comment: this one will link to the same page, but with a php value sent.

Comment: With respect, you need to understand how web-pages work and their lifecycle in the browser (e.g. load, unload, etc) first, otherwise we can't really help you because you wouldn't understand what we're telling you to do. It's as if someone who barely knows how to read is being asked to write a dictionary.

Comment: Correct, I don't understand your question because you still haven't adequately explained what the problem actually is. For example, you still haven't clarified if the jumping behavior is before or after `unload` or `load` in the page's lifecycle - or if other scripts are running in your page, nor have you posted the rendered HTML output from your PHP script. The problem you're describing has many entirely different root causes and I have no way of knowing which of those apply in your case because you haven't provided sufficient detail.

Comment: If it jumps to the top with no page reload, maybe you have some javascript or something over there, maybe using chatLink element. If it jumps with page reload, maybe $row['unique_id'] is empty and you go to the same page, just seeming to go to the top.

Comment: If you just want to jump back to a specific element further down the result page, then make sure that element has an ID, and include a corresponding fragment identifier in your link href then ...

Comment: _"so with the same respect, you can just refrain from commenting if you don't know how to help"_ - By posting here, you already requested that people invest time to look into your problem. So if you don't manage to ask a halfway proper question to begin with, you have already wasted people's time - and they don't get it back, by you going "well ignore the question and don't comment then."

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store scrollValue before leaving page:

```
window.onscroll = e => localStorage.setItem('scrollTop', document.body.scrollTop);
```

Then, when new page load, set scroll back:

```
window.onload = e => {
    const scrollTop= localStorage.getItem('scrollTop');
    document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: `window.onscroll = e =>` - this is inappropriate for performance reasons (as well as breaking any other scroll event-listeners) You should use `addEventListener` with `{ passive: true }` otherwise you'll wreck scrolling UX.

Comment: Also, using `onload` is also a bad idea because `onload` is often raised _seconds_ or even minutes after the HTML finished loading (as `onload` is raised after all external resources like images have loaded) which will be jarring to the user. Instead use `DOMContentLoaded` or an inline `<script>` which appears immediately after the element which should be jumped-to (that way it will work even when the HTML alone is megabytes-long and the target element is present in the DOM).

Comment: Also, `localStorage` only stores `string` values - but `scrollTop` is a `number` property. While JS will handle type-juggling for you, it isn't reliable. You also need to verify that the value itself is valid before setting `scrollTop`. You should also check that the viewport dimensions haven't changed between page-loads.